# I am trying to extract text from multiple images with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, ocr, text-extraction

This is my code

```py
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import pytesseract
import os

#Define path to tessaract.exe
path_to_tesseract = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

#Define path to images folder
path_to_images = r'C:\Users\vIBRancy\Desktop\quantic_trust _file\images'

#Point tessaract_cmd to tessaract.exe
pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = path_to_tesseract

#Get the file names in the directory
for root, dirs, file_names in os.walk(path_to_images):
    #Iterate over each file name in the folder
    for file_name in file_names:
        #Open image with PIL
        img = Image.open(path_to_images + file_name)

        #Extract text from image
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang = 'eng')
        with open('quantictrustfiles.txt','w') as file:     
      
            file.write(text)
            print(text)
```

Here is the response from the terminal:

```
PS C:\Users\vIBRancy\Desktop\quantic_trust _file> & C:/Users/vIBRancy/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe "c:/Users/vIBRancy/Desktop/quantic_trust _file/quantict_trust_file.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\vIBRancy\Desktop\quantic_trust _file\quantict_trust_file.py", line 19, in <module>
    img = Image.open(path_to_images + file_name)
  File "C:\Users\vIBRancy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 3068, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\vIBRancy\\Desktop\\quantic_trust _file\\imagesIMG_0096.jpeg'
```

I don't know what to do. Anyone to help.

Comment: Use "os.path.join" to connect path and filename. A simple `+` fails due to a missing backslash.

Comment: just replace open image by `img = Image.open(path_to_images + '/' + file_name)`. because a slash is missing in path.

Comment: i tend to use  \\ for separators in windows (the path sepatator is different for the different operating systems. Or alternatively `path.join()`.

Comment: @IbraheemAlawode cool!